# How to query single row with subquery having multiple row?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have room table and member table. Those are ..

**Room** table

```
----------------
| id  |   name |  
----------------
|  1  |    A   |
----------------
|  2  |    B   |
----------------
```

**Member** table

```
--------------------------
| id | username | room_id |
--------------------------
| 1  | Johnson  |   1     |
--------------------------
| 2  | Laylar   |   1     |
--------------------------
| 3  | Myia     |   1     |
--------------------------
| 4  | Natalia  |   1     |
--------------------------
| 5  | Gusion   |   2     |
--------------------------
| 6  | Saber    |   2     |
--------------------------
| 7  | Cyclop   |   2     |
--------------------------
| 8  | Akai     |   1     |
--------------------------
```

I want to get query result like this..

```
[
 {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "A",
   "members" : [
      {"id": 1,"username": "Johnson"},
      {"id": 2,"username": "Laylar"},
      {"id": 3,"username": "Myia"}
   ]
 },
 {
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "B",
   "members" : [
      {"id": 5,"username": "Gusion"},
      {"id": 6,"username": "Saber"},
      {"id": 7,"username": "Cyclop"}
   ]
 }
]
```

I try like this

```
SELECT room.*, (SELECT member.id, member.username FROM member WHERE member.room_id = room.id LIMIT 3) AS members FROM room INNER JOIN member ON room.id = member.room_id;
```

I got this error
`ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

And, when I try with GROUP_CONCAT the result is ok but LIMIT is not working!!

Query is

```
SELECT room.*, (SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id', member.id, 'username', member.username) separator ','), ']') FROM member WHERE member.room_id = room.id LIMIT 3) AS members FROM room JOIN member ON room.id=member.room_id GROUP BY room.id;
```

The result is

```
[
 {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "A",
   "members" : [
      {"id": 1,"username": "Johnson"},
      {"id": 2,"username": "Laylar"},
      {"id": 3,"username": "Myia"},
      {"id": 4,"username": "Natalia"},
      {"id": 8,"username": "Akai"}
   ]
 },
 {
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "B",
   "members" : [
      {"id": 5,"username": "Gusion"},
      {"id": 6,"username": "Saber"},
      {"id": 7,"username": "Cyclop"}
   ]
 }
]
```

**LIMIT 3** is not working!!! I don't want to get all members. I just want to get 3 members.

How to query it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `row_number` with `partition by` to provide record IDs for filtering just before the aggregation:

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object('id', t.room_id, 'name', r.name, 'members', t.members)) 
from (select m.room_id, json_arrayagg(json_object('id', m.id, 'username', m.username)) members 
     from (select row_number() over (partition by m1.room_id) r, m1.* from member m1) m 
     where m.r < 4 group by m.room_id) t 
join room r on r.id = t.room_id
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qPxMkIHm).

Comment: Wow!! 
100% Working. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this solution good for having 10 million records database? Please reply me.